# Ways to organize Maven project with lots of artifacts

Tags: java, maven

I'm trying to organise my maven project.

Let's say my project is called "awesome". "awesome" has several artifact, each of them built differently (e.g., some of them may be built with some plugin, others are built with some other plugins): in general thse build-configurations are finite and limited (let's say there are at most 3 different ways to build an artifact), however, each artifact can only be built with exactly one build (e.g., the `utility` artifact is built with `maven-jar-plugin` configured in a particular way, while the artifact `client-ui` is built with `maven-war-plugin` configured in a particular way).

Now, I know I could organize the maven project as follows:

```
awesome-root
 |---jars
 |    |--- utility
 |    |--- client-model
 |    |--- task-model
 |    |--- supplier-model
 |    |--- client-logic
 |    |--- task-logic
 |    ---- supplier-logic
 |---wars
      |--- client-ui
      |--- task-ui
      ---- supplier-ui
```

This way, each particular configuration build can be put inside the `build --> plugins` section of the projects `jars` and `wars`, while general properties/dependency management/plugin management can be put in `awesome-root`.

**Problem:**
I quickly realized that the developers generates artifacts closely related with eachother but with different builds. In the previous example, we can notice that the artifacts can be grouped in this other way:

```
awesome-root
 |--- tasks
 |     |--- task-model
 |     |--- task-logic
 |     ---- task-ui
 |--- clients
 |     |--- client-model
 |     |--- client-logic
 |     ---- client-ui
 |--- supplier
 |     |--- supplier-model
 |     |--- supplier-logic
 |     ---- supplier-ui
 |--- others
       |--- utility
```

The main advantage of this grouping is that `tasks`, `clients` and `suppliers` are 3 different, *independent* software sectors. When the developer needs to make a change in the, let's say, `client` sectors, she has everything she needs in a small part of the file system (or in the project explorer tab in an IDE, like Eclipse). Viceversa, in the first mapping, the `clients` software sector is scrambled all over in the project repository.

While this may not be a big deal, if "awesome" project starts to get really big, with a lot of artifacts and so on, finding all the related parts of `clients` sectors start to be annoying (not impossible, IDEs offer searches for this purpose).
I'd say the second structure is much better, developer wise.

However, It's seems difficult to implement this strategy in maven: the main difficulty is to where to put the different build configurations for each artifacts (e.g., `*-ui` needs to be built in a different way of `*-model`).

- One may be tempted to put such configurations in `client-ui`, `client-logic`, `client-model`, but this would mean duplicate configuration build everywhere (e.g, `client-ui`, `supplier-ui`, `task-ui` has the same build configuration): if a build configuration needs to be changed, you need to change all the other copies;
- Another solution might be to declare plugins management in `awesome-root` and them write the plugin definition in each artifactId: while this seems better, it still suffer from the same duplication problem of option 1;
- Use archetype to generate poms with the correct build configuration: same as above;
- Profiles: profiles are not inherited and they depend only on system properties, not maven's one;

**My questions are**:

- Is the second structure impossible to achieve in Maven? Is there a way?
- If not, do I need to bite the bullet and set on the first structure?
- Is there any alternative? (I'm trying not to propose a XY problem, any alternative is appreciated);

**Additional information**:

- OS: Ubuntu 18.04.3 (bionic), 64 bit
- java version: openjdk 11.0.4 2019-07-16
- IDE: Eclipse 4.10.0
- m2e plugin: 1.10.0.20181127-2120

Thanks for any kind reply

Comment: Question: Why do you need different configuration to build either a war or a jar ? Can you explain that more in detail..? (I have organized builds with 800+ modules within a single build)..I think possible is everything...the domain shows where to put different trees of things...

Comment: the hierarchy was just an example: in reality I want to work with OSGi in mind, so some artifacts are bundles (hence needs to be processed with `maven-bnd-plugin`. Others are WARs. Others are  WABs. Others are plain bundles but require less dependencies than the first artifact category. The problem is not that I have too many modules. The problem is that the modules have eterogeneus build/dependencies. I hope I made my point, or maybe I didnt' fully understood your question. :)

Comment: Can you tell which Java version you are using?

Comment: question updated with some system information

Comment: Another option I don't know if you've considered: define different parents. Although `awesome-root` is the *aggregator* for the modules, it need not be the *parent* -- you could create `ui-parent`, `logic-parent` etc., put the shared build configuration in there, and make the modules use these parents as desired. May or may not work for you...

Comment: I've read [this link](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Inheritance_v) and I was aware of that possibility. However, I've read online that several plugins tends to misbehave if used (most notably `maven-release-plugin`). Can you provide (by answer this question) a MWE? Would be very appreciated.

Comment: That's a bit more work than I'm prepared to go into - a meaningful demonstration would probably involve a project with six submodules (two parents; and two children of each). You could then define different plugin executions in the parents and verify that those executions were honoured by the children. I'd encourage you to try this experiment yourself and see if it works for you. I've done similar things in the past without causing any problems with the release plugin.

Comment: @Koldar What kind of misbehave are you talking about?

Comment: `maven-release-plugin` is cumbersome, and in modern CD environment it might be useless anyway. Are there other plugins that concern you? I'd go with `<pluginManagement>` and if declaring `<plugins>` in each sub-module is a real problem for you - you could create your own `<packaging>` that would declare which plugins to run.

Comment: @khmarbaise I was specifically referring to `maven-release-plugin`. I'll try some of your suggestion. Let's see what comes up